# How to select correct app.config file at build time in TFS?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, msbuild, continuous-integration

Our Team Foundation Server has to build three different versions of the same solution. The only difference between them is the `app.config` file which should be changed for each build. How do I select correct file during the build?

What I want to do is switch app.config file and then build, repeat for each file. Ie:

```
<Replace file="app.config" with="app.config.one"> <!-- and then -->
<SolutionToBuild Include="project.sln"/>

<Replace file="app.config" with="app.config.two"> <!-- and then -->
<SolutionToBuild Include="project.sln"/>

<Replace file="app.config" with="app.config.three"> <!-- and then -->
<SolutionToBuild Include="project.sln"/>
```

(I realise the above is näive, but it shows what I want to do).

I have tried setting properties back and forth, using `BeforeCompileSolution` etc etc but nope.

Btw, this is a ClickOnce project (using the Publish target), so I have to select the correct `app.config` file before the compilation step due to file integrity checks as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725460/msbuild-click-once-issues-with-manifest) question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be impossible, so I created three different builds to solve it. Each build copies a single file in the pre-build target. I now have three tfsbuild.proj files which is exactly the same, except for the file name. Sucks, but it works.